# I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for a 2d array. its going wrong at index 6 for some reason. when i equals 6, j keeps incrementing infinite

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int dimension;
int entry;
int winningStreak[4];


scanf("%d", &dimension);

char** grid = malloc (sizeof(char*)*dimension);

for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
{
    grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * dimension);

    for(int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = ' ';

        printf("\n%d...%d",i,j);
    }

    winningStreak[i] = rand()+i;
}
```

//I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for a 2d array. its going wrong at index 6 for some reason. when i equals 6, j keeps incrementing infinite

Comment: `winningStreak[i] = rand()+i;` Once `i >= 4` this is an invalid array access.

Comment: input: 10//

0...0 
0...1
0...2
0...3
0...4
0...5
0...6
0...7
0...8
0...9
1...0
1...1
1...2
1...3
1...4
1...5
1...6
1...7
1...8
1...9
2...0
2...1
2...2
2...3
2...4
2...5
2...6
2...7
2...8
2...9
3...0
3...1
3...2
3...3
3...4
3...5
3...6
3...7
3...8
3...9
4...0
4...1
4...2
4...3
4...4
4...5
4...6
4...7
4...8
4...9
5...0
5...1
5...2
5...3
5...4
5...5
5...6
5...7
5...8
5...9
6...0
6...1
6...2
6...3
6...4
6...5
6...6
6...7
6...8
6...9
6...10
6...11
6...12
6...13
6...14
6...15
6...16
6...17
6...18
6...19
6...20
6...21

Comment: Try dynamic VLA. `char (*grid)[dimensions] = malloc(dimensions * sizeof *grid);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the value of i doesn't change just the int inside the array which shouldn't be a problem, no?

Comment: @tstanisl that line gave me all types of error

Comment: @JohnnyMopp you are right sir. I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Whatever compiler it is, always enable *Full-Warnings* so your compiler can identify out-of-bounds conditions and issue a diagnostic for you. Add the option to treat all warnings as errors -- to keep yourself honest. Never accept code until it compiles cleanly -- without warning. `sizeof(char)` is superfluous, it is defined as `1`.